How to fix Graphics driver error in Windows 11 ARM64 using UTM in my Macbook Pro M3 Pro Image?
I've installed Windows 11 ARM64 using UTM in my Macbook Pro M3 Pro and I have also installed the SPICE tools/drivers along with it.
Then I have installed Alias 2024 Learning Edition in it but I am getting an error about the display driver when I open Alias.
I am attaching the Screenshot, and I am happy to provide more info need to solve this.

What resources can I pursue to fix this sort of issue?

Make sure you have selected one of the Emulated Display Cards that supports GL acceleration.  An ARM VM defaults to one that does not.
These have -gl in their name.
You may find https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/issues/4285 useful.


Thanks! Do I need to reinstall the SPICE driver after changing the Emulated display card?

I tried virtio-ramfb-gl, installed UTM guest drivers after turning on the instance but still facing the same error. Its the same case with virtio-gpu-gl-pci. When I tried virtio-gpu-gl-device, the windows screen became totally blank. Am I missing to do something after I change the display card?

I don't know whether you have to reinstall Windows or not.  May I suggest using VMWare rather than UTM?
